# SUMIFS and/or QUERY inside ARRAYFORMULA

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Google spreadsheet sample: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MdRjm5QmKY_vaah9c3GrvH6dDOBCQX_zvCubvN0akmk/edit?usp=sharing

Im trying to get the sum of all values for each ID. The values im trying to add up are found in the Source tab while the calculations are done in the Output. My desired values are based on 2 things: ID and Date. The Id is supposed to match and the Date is supposed to be February. I tried first just using a sumif with just matching ID and it worked using this formula: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="",, SUMIF(Source!A:A,A2:A,Source!B:B)))`

But when I add the 2nd critera and use a sumifs function, it only outputs for the first id. Here is the sumifs formula I used: `=ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIFS(Source!B2:B,Source!A2:A,A2:A,Source!C2:C,">="&DATE(2021,2,1),Source!C2:C,"<="&DATE(2021,2,28)))`

I tried using query as some of the answers I found online suggested to use it but it also outputs the first data only, here is the query formula I used `=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(Source!A2:C,"select sum(B) where A = '"&Output!A2:A&"' and C >= date '"&TEXT(DATEVALUE("2/1/2021"),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and C <= date '"&TEXT(DATEVALUE("2/28/2021"),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' label sum(B) '' "))`

I know this is possible by making a temporary query/filter where you only include desired dates and from there I can use SUMIF, but I will be needing to make a monthly total and making 12 of these calculated temporary filters/query would take up a lot of space since we have a lot of data so I want to avoid this option if possible. Is there a better fix to this situation?

Comment: QUERY and SUMIFS don't work with ARRAYFORMULA. SUMIF does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by Astrotia - `=arrayformula(sumif(I3:I20&month(K3:K20), A2:A6&2, J3:J20))`